# Where to Put Rails Data Collection Task

Tags: api, architecture, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so I imagine this will be an easy one for someone out there but I can't seem to find a definite answer. I have a web application that, on a daily basis, will query different APIs and record the data in models I have made. What I don't know is where to put this and what kind of Ruby structure to use. I'm not sure if this would be better as a Concern, a Module, or just a script/runner. The routines will be quite specific, which is why I don't think a Concern fits nor does a Module because its not like these would easily extend a class. That is why I'm leaning towards a script/runner but it is something I would like to be able to call from cron as well as controllers. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a rake task? This is exactly what they are best at.

This railscast is not in his prime anymore but its content is still relevant: http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background